# Matlab: trying to fix the "RGB color data not yet supported in Painter's mode" warning

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use the [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) matlab tool to export matlab figures in vector format (pdf or eps).

When trying do that, I get "Warning: RGB color data not yet supported in Painter's mode" and none of the colored parts are shown.

The author has addressed this issue in the README.md (in the package) with

```
**RGB color data not yet supported in Painter's mode** - you will see this as a warning if you try to export a figure which contains patch objects whose face or vertex colors are specified as a an RGB colour, rather than an index into the colormap, using the painters renderer (the default renderer for vector output). This problem can arise if you use `pcolor`, for example. This is a problem with MATLAB's painters renderer, which also affects `print`; there is currently no fix available in export_fig (other than to export to bitmap). The suggested workaround is to avoid colouring patches using RGB. First, try to use colours in the figure's colourmap (instructions [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-6OTPQE/)) - change the colourmap, if necessary. If you are using `pcolor`, try using [uimagesc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11368) (on the file exchange) instead.
```

And in http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-6OTPQE/ we have the accepted solution as

```
s = surf(peaks(50), 'CData', cat(3, 0.8*ones(50), ones(50), 0.65*ones(50)));
rgb_colors = get(s, 'CData');
[i, map] = rgb2ind(rgb_colors, 64);
set(s, 'CData', double(i));
colormap(map);
```

Now I have a figure which has some contour lines and the problem might be the way I'm accessing their handles, because by trying this:

```
>> h = findobj(gca, 'Type', 'Line')

h =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

i.e. no lines are found. So I'm currently using this:

```
>> h = get(gca, 'children')
```

And then, to convert the colors, I'll use the subsequent lines from the forum post, which give an error:

```
>> [i, map] = rgb2ind(rgb_colors, 64)
Error using cq
First input must be a uint8 array.

Error in rgb2ind (line 89)
        [map,X] = cq(RGB,m);
```

I'll also output the contents of rgb_colors:

```
>> rgb_colors
rgb_colors = 

    [2x451x3   double]
    [2x480x3   double]
    [2x359x3   double]
    [2x311x3   double]
    [2x279x3   double]
    [2x263x3   double]
    [2x259x3   double]
    [2x253x3   double]
    [2x261x3   double]
    [2x269x3   double]
    [2x260x3   double]
    [2x261x3   double]
    [2x261x3   double]
    [2x259x3   double]
    [2x263x3   double]
    [2x259x3   double]
    [2x259x3   double]
    [2x253x3   double]
    [2x255x3   double]
    [2x255x3   double]
    [2x255x3   double]
    [3x34577x3 double]
    []
```

And I'm sorry if this is very basic, I don't have much experience in matlab.